# iCloud Drive backup with rsync shows huge disparity with size reported by Finder

Tags: icloud

I am trying to complete an iCloud Drive backup onto an external disk shows huge disparities. Running an `rsync` command on the folder:

```
~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/
```

pushes 11GB of data onto the external drive.

However, <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> on the iCloud Drive folder calculates 234GB on the disk.

What can explain such a major gap?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Have you enabled "Optimize Mac Storage" in System Preferences > Apple ID? This setting will cause your Mac to store the full contents of iCloud Drive, but only if there is enough space.

Comment: No, that option has always been disabled

Comment: I managed to copy the files to the drive by dragging the folder over, but could not find an rsync friendly solution.